# how can i use span with br

Tags: web-services, jquery

My requirment is:---

```
  Selected outlet:    Selected table:    Selected employee:          Logged in as:
      Wine Bar              15               EmpName                   admin (admin)
```

I'm using my html span tag as like

```
   <div class="my_dynamic_panel">
     <span class="outletTitle right_border">Selected outlet:<b>Wine Bar</b></span>
     <span class="outletTitle right_border">Selected table:<b>15</b></span>
      <span class="outletTitle right_border">Selected employee:<b></b></span>
      <span class="outletTitle ">Logged in as:<b>admin</b>
      (admin)</span>
</div>
```

Then my output as like

```
    Selected outlet:Wine Bar Selected table:15 Selected employee: Logged in as:admin (admin)
```

if i use break tag(br) inside span

```
    <div class="my_dynamic_panel">
     <span class="outletTitle right_border">Selected outlet:<br><b>Wine Bar</b></span>
     <span class="outletTitle right_border">Selected table:<br><b>15</b></span>
      <span class="outletTitle right_border">Selected employee:<br><b></b></span>
      <span class="outletTitle ">Logged in as:<br><b>admin</b>
      (admin)</span>
</div>
```

then my output is

```
Selected outlet:
Wine Bar Selected table:
15 Selected employee:
Logged in as:
admin (admin)
```

I'm not good in css. i want to use span tag with br. please help me

Comment: why `data` is blank when your `url` contains parameter, don't pass parameter with the `url` use `data` instead

Comment: i also tried by this way
data: "username="+un+ "password="+pw+ "",

Answer (score 0):

You can construct your url like :

```
myurl="http://localhost/EServices/retrieve.aspx;"
Ajax Data = data : {command : 'get_authentication', username: un , password : pw}

type: "POST",
url:myurl,
dataType: "xml",
async: true,
data: {command : 'get_authentication', username : un , password : pw},
contentType: "text/xml",
crossDomain:true,
processData:false,
```

instead of

```
myurl="http://localhost/EServices/retrieve.aspx?command=get_authentication&username="+un+"&password="+pw;
```

Comment: @user1685467 Why use `crossDomain:true` ? are you accessing `ajax url` from different domain?

Comment: why use `processData:false` ?

Comment: after removing processData:false i will going to success part my service still return null in alert message
textnull

Comment: can you please post your `get_authentication method` logic.

Comment: :---->i am getting all request data in a streamformat(text) and i don't know how to pass text or stream as a request